# onClickListener on a LinearLayout

Tags: android

Got a little problem with a functionality I'd like to implement.

I've got a `LinearLayout`, containing 2 `TextViews`. I'd want to set a `onClickListener` on it, so that it would behave just like an item in a `ListView`.

I've tried some possible implementation of this, and got it working using the xml attribute `android:onClick` of the `LinearLayout`.

As I want the application to visually react to a click on the `LinearLayout` (as in a `ListView`), I put this in the listener callback method :

```
l.setBackgroundColor(android.R.drawable.list_selector_background);
```

l is a `LinearLayout` object, initialised with `findViewById()`;

I get an application not responding whenever I try to click on the layout. I tried to replace the code in the callback method by a Toast message show up, and it works, so I guess the problem is in the `setBackgroundColor`.

*Is anyone familiar with this?*

PS: sorry, I can't post more code right now, I'm at work.

Comment: Use DDMS or `adb logcat` to examine your stack trace to find the source of your exception. Edit this question and post it here if you cannot understand it.

Answer (score 62):

You have to set `LinearLayout` attribute `android:clickable="true"` in the xml layout file or `setClickable(true)` in the java activity code.

Comment: I think ```android:clickable = "true"``` would be the syntax.

Answer (score 5):

i noticed that all the advices above don't helpt as long as any of the child elements inside the LinearLayout has the attribute android:textIsSelectable="true".

Answer (score 3):

I found that that setClickable(true) would still cause clicks to go to children of the linearlayout.  I found that to have the LinearLayout capture the touch instead of it's children I had to override the dispatchTouchEvent method so I created a subclass of LinearLayout for just this purpose.  Seems like an ugly solution though.

Comment: I think that's where android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" would be cleaner that custom view. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:descendantFocusability

Answer (score 2):

you should set the LinearLayout's focusable to true and set all the children view's focusable to false, don't use the android:clickable="true", but you can't see the effect of the click of the linelayout. BTW, the best way is to implement the onTouchEvent api.

Answer (score 1):

android:clickable="true" works perfectly under one condition.
Youhave to put the childs inside the LilnearLayout to android:clickable="false".

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, I've been trying for an hour all the answers in SO but none worked.

Then I realized I just had to **promote my LinearLayout to the bottom of the layout**, since other views blocked it, and then it worked, **without adding ANY special attributes to the layout**.

Putting it here in case it might help someone someday.

Comment: How did you put it to the bottom?

Comment: what do you mean with bottom, do you mean z-layer or direction ?