# LinearLayout OnClickListener not responding

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I'm creating a custom widget by expanding LinearLayout. One of the elements in my custom widget is a linear layout, inflated from another layout. When I set the OnClickListener it is not responding. Can you please advise?

Thanks!

Comment: Could we have some code please?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of  using [setOnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) use [setOnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) 
This code will work as a onclick event

```
YourLinearLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            boolean returnValue = true;
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){ //on touch release
                returnValue = false; //prevent default action on release
                //do something here
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
    });
```

And then add this to your LinearLayout class to intercept child touch events

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return true; //will prevent child touch events 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you declared the LinearLayout clickable?

You can do this either in the XML:

android:clickable="true"

or in Java code:

myLinearLayout.setClickable( true );

Also see the other StackOverflow thread on this question:

[onClickListener on a LinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130875/onclicklistener-on-a-linearlayout)

Comment: layout.setClickable( true ); worked for me. I tried from XML flag but not working

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you put all childs inside LinearLayout to android:clickable="false". Than myLinearLayout.setClickable( true ) works for me.