# LinearLayout and OnItemClickListener not working

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, onitemclicklistener

I've read that's possible to [add an OnItemClickListener on a LinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130875/onclicklistener-on-a-linearlayout) as if it was a ListView , but when I try to add it to the LinearLayout, it throws an error that's says that isn't defined the method for LinearLayouts. Do you know how can I set the onItemClickListener on the layout? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I do not understand what you are looking for? Ar you trying to make the entire layout clickable? And what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add an `OnItemClickListener` to a LinearLayout, but you can add an `OnClickListener`. You will need to set the LinearLayout as `clickable`.

Example XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true" >
```

Example Java:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

If you need more help post your relevant code and your LogCat errors.

Comment: But I can get that view was pressed?

Comment: This will only work when you click on the LinearLayout or a child View that doesn't have it's own `OnClickListener`. For example, if you click a Button inside this LinearLayout, the Button's `OnClickListener` will work, not the LinearLayouts.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code,** 
**I hope it will work**

```
linearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1);
ll.getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
              //your code here
              functionCalledOnItemClicked();

           }
      });
```